# Get height of a DIV that changes height dynamically

Tags: jquery

EXAMPLE: http://jsbin.com/ewiko4/5/

So I have some Dynamic divs that I need to figure out the height of when they change. I can get the height when the document loads but it won't update.

**In the example I've added a make bigger button but irl it will be changed via jq & ajax**

Yup, I can't add a callback to the animation button because it wont't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this edit](http://jsbin.com/ewiko4/8/edit) of your jsbin.

Couple of changes:

1. Your window events could be binded at the same time with `$(window).bind('load resize', resizeFrame)`
2. You want to call the `resizeFrame` as a callback of the animation to let it know the sizes changed...
3. If you don't have control of the animation function changing the height (as indicated by your comment) you can use a `setInterval` to poll the heights.

---

```
setInterval(resizeFrame, 150);
```

Would call your `resizeFrame` function every 150 ms.  You can check the heights, see if they've changed, and do whatever you need to...

Comment: Unfortunately the animating button is just there for the example. The div sizes are changed by the multi view control in asp so I can't us a callback on the animation.

Comment: Thanks for $(window).bind('load resize', resizeFrame) btw

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is call outerHeight() again:

```
$('#makeBigger').click(function(){
  $('#buyNow').animate({
        height: '+=10px'
  }, function() {
    var newHeight = $('#buyNow').outerHeight();
    // ...
  })
});
```

If you pass a function to `animate()` as the second argument like that, then that function will be called when the animation is complete. At that point, you can get the new height and do whatever you want with it. If the `<div>` changes because its content is reloaded, you'd do the same thing in the callback from the ajax routine.

Comment: Unfortunately the animating button is just there for the example. The div sizes are changed by the multi view control in asp so I can't us a callback on the animation.

Comment: If that's the case, you can just set up an interval timer to check the `<div>` every 100 milliseconds or so. So long as you don't do very much work in the timer handler, it won't have much of an effect on performance or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Set Div Height

```
var h = $('#content').height();
```

Get Div Height

```
var h = 500;
$('#content').height(h);
```

http://api.jquery.com/height/

You need to find an event that is triggered when the MultiView's content is changed. Once you have that, you should be able to call a function which has the appropriate XXX.height() call. Im not familiar enough with ASP to give you specifics.

Comment: thanks for the jquery api link but so far I've been through .height .outerHeight .innerHeight .live & .delegate and the livequery plugin. None of them will update it live when content in them changes